# How to solve Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement> | undefined'.ts(2322)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, onclick, dropdown, react-bootstrap

I'm working on a web application using React and react-bootstrap, (in TypeScript).
I want to make a dropdown menu in the Navbar to change the language of the page. I've got a list of langauges and applying map on the list to make <Dropdown.Item> like this:

```
const languageList = [
    {
        Id: "en",
        Language: "English"
    },
...
]
const [t, i18n] = useTranslation();
const [lang, setLang] = useState<string>();
useEffect(() => {
  i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
}, [lang, i18n]);

const handleClick = (lg: string) => {
    setLang(lg)
}
...
return (
  <Dropdown>
    <Dropdown.Toggle variant="outline-secondary" id="dropdown-basic">
       language
    </Dropdown.Toggle>
    <Dropdown.Menu>
       {languageList.map((item) => {
         return(
          <Dropdown.Item value={item.Id} onClick={handleClick(item.Id)>
            {item.Language}
          </Dropdown.Item>
         )
       })}
    </Dropdown.Menu>
  </Dropdown>
)
```

Without the **onClick={handleClick(item.Id)** in the <Dropdown.Item> tag, this code gives me a dropdown menu like this:
[image]

However, when I add onClick, it gives me these errors: 
**Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler | undefined'.ts(2322)**

 and 
**Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.**

If anyone knows how to fix this, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is wrong

```
 <Dropdown.Item value={item.Id} onClick={handleClick(item.Id)>
     {item.Language}
 </Dropdown.Item>
```

Should be

```
 <Dropdown.Item value={item.Id} onClick={() => handleClick(item.Id)}>
     {item.Language}
 </Dropdown.Item>
```

At the moment you are trying to assign the result of the function as the onClick-handler. Either pass the variable without execution or create a anonymous function that runs your desired function. If you need to pass a parameter you have to use the latter.